# Incorrect lazy initialization

Tags: java, findbugs

Findbug told me that I use incorrect lazy initialization.

```
public static Object getInstance() {
    if (instance != null) {
        return instance;
    }

    instance = new Object();
    return instance;
}
```

I don't see anything wrong here. Is it wrong behaviour of findbug, or I missed something?

Comment: Maybe it expects `if (instance == null) instance = new Object(); return instance;` ?

Comment: @Matt: it is lazy initialisation alright, and it only makes a singleton if all of the class's constructors are private.

Comment: Yes, it does seem to expect the pattern to be:

```
if (instance == null) {
   instance = new Object();
}

return instance;
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Findbug is referencing a potential threading issue.  In a multi thread environment, there would be potential for your singleton to be created more than once with your current code.

There is a lot of reading [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-01-2001/jw-0112-singleton.html), but it will help explain.

The race condition here is on the `if check`.  On the first call, a thread will get into the `if check`, and will create the instance and assign it to 'instance'.  But there is potential for another thread to become active between the `if check` and the instance creation/assignment.  This thread could also pass the `if check` because the assignment hasn't happened yet.  Therefore, two (or more, if more threads got in) instances would be created, and your threads would have references to different objects.

Comment: Making the method `synchronized` would be the simplest cure to this problem.

Comment: @John:  Correct, that is almost always the best solution in this case.

Comment: Just making it synchronized will incur the synchronization overhead on each call; you only need it on the first call.

Comment: @antlersoft, But you don't actually even need it on a non-threaded app.

Comment: Multiple instantiation is only one possibility. Even worse, the compiler could reorder instructions and the caller could have an instance of a partially constructed object with default values.

Answer (score 24):

Your code is slightly more complex than needed which might be why it's confused.

Edit: It's definitely the threading issue as the others posted but thought I'd post the double lock check implementation here for reference below:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
private static volatile Object instance; // must be declared volatile

public static Object getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) { // avoid sync penalty if we can
        synchronized (lock) { // declare a private static Object to use for mutex
            if (instance == null) {  // have to do this inside the sync
                instance = new Object();
            }
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Is this really an improvement over making the whole method synchronized and only doing the test once?

Comment: I've always been told that synchronization is more expensive than an if check. I've never actually measured it myself.

Comment: Read here for a good discussion on how to do a double lock check (its more tricky than it should be): http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: For this to work properly, your lock must be `volatile`.  I know you have already illustrated this, but I think you should make it a bit more explicit in the answer.

Comment: I've added a comment to call attention to the volatile keyword

Comment: It doesn't help to declare the variable `myLock` as `volatile`. Instead, you have to declare the variable `instance` as `volatile`.

Comment: @nosid Excellent observation, I misspoke when I suggested that the Lock should be `volatile`.  It is indeed the `instance` variable that should be `volatile`.

Answer (score 13):

**NOTE**: JohnKlehm's double lock checking solution is better. Leaving this answer here for historical reasons.

It should actually be

```
public synchronized static Object getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Object();
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I like this code better than how it was originally, but this does not explain why the original code is wrong.

Comment: At the time of posting one of the answers had already mentioned the ill effects of a non synchronized lazy instantitation in a multi threaded enviornment. I just put it into code. :)

Comment: This still doesn't fix the violation though.

Comment: Ah - it's synchronized now. I missed that (or it was changed). With synchronized, it does fix the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a lock around instantiation to make this correct

> LI: Incorrect lazy initialization of static field
>   (LI_LAZY_INIT_STATIC)
>
> This method contains an unsynchronized lazy initialization of a
>   non-volatile static field. Because the compiler or processor may
>   reorder instructions, threads are not guaranteed to see a completely
>   initialized object, if the method can be called by multiple threads.
>   You can make the field volatile to correct the problem. For more
>   information, see the Java Memory Model web site.

Answer (score 3):

You missed multi threading issue,

```
private static Object instance;

public static synchronized Object getInstance() {
    return (instance != null ? instance : (instance = new Object()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to John Klehm for posted sample

also may try to assign object instance in sychronised block directly

```
synchronized (MyCurrentClass.myLock=new Object())
```

i.e.

```
private static volatile Object myLock = new Object();

public static Object getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) { // avoid sync penalty if we can
        synchronized (MyCurrentClass.myLock**=new Object()**) { // declare a private static Object to use for mutex
            if (instance == null) {  // have to do this inside the sync
                instance = new Object();
            }
        }
    }

    return instance;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your static object is not  synchronized. Moreover your method is not a lazy initialization. Normally what you do is you keep a Map of object,and you initialize the desired one on demand. So you do not initialize all of them at the beginning rather than calling them when it is needed(called).

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.5: the instance should be volatile and yould integrate a tmp variable to avoid using an instance that is created but its initialization is not finished yet.

```
private static volatile Object myLock = new Object();
private static volatile Object instance;

public static Object getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        Object tmpObj;
        synchronized (myLock) {
            tmpObj = instance;
            if (tmpObj == null) {
                tmpObj = new Object();
            }
        }
        instance = tmpObj;
    }

    return instance;

}
```